# "Could not find main class error" On windows, not linux

Tags: java, windows, classpath

I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PageStore
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PageStore
   .
   .
   .
Could not find the main class: PageStore. Program will exit.
```

When running my Java program on Windows.
 
It runs fine on linux and osx.

I'm running it from a .sh or .bat file containing:

```
javac -cp sesame.jar SimpleGraph.java PeerHandler.java ClientHandler.java Router.java PageStore.java
java -cp sesame.jar:slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar:slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar:. PageStore
```

The javac command works fine and it compiles on both systems. All the other solutions I've seen online have been to add the current directory to the class path, which I already have, and say nothing about working on one OS but not the other.

Answer (score 3):

The path separator for the classpath on windows is the semicolon, `;`.

Try:

```
java -cp sesame.jar;slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar;. PageStore
```

Comment: well thats silly that they're different. Tried it and still got the same error though..

Comment: is a bit silly, but consider that the classpath includes _paths_, and paths in windows can already contain the colon as part of the drive path, e.g. _C:\Users\Adam_ and you'll see why this is necessary. You're still getting the _same_ specific error included in your question? Make sure that you replaced all the semicolons, and/or copy the command line from the answer

Comment: mmm, true, I understand now. Do linux versions of java accept both separators?

Also, yes its the same error, verbatim..

Comment: @AdamMiller: after the `javac` command succeeds, do you see the class files in the current directory? e.g. running `dir` or `ls`, do you see a _PageStore.class_ file? Also, are you running your compile/run script from that same directory?

Comment: Yes and yes, everything is in the same directory and the PageStore.class file is in it...